# add softly linked attribute spring-data-rest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have just a straight forward question.

Just imagine I have an entity class which is mapped to a table with columns. I just need to introduced a new attribute to the same class, whose value needs to be fetch from a column in another table (What I mean by softly linked).

I know this is not quite a clean requirement.

Anyway, is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA/Hibernate Join and Fetch single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310688/jpa-hibernate-join-and-fetch-single-column)

Comment: @M.Justin unfortunately no

Comment: OK.  I realize it's an almost 4-year-old question so you probably moved past it years ago, but it's not quite clear to me what this question is asking if that's not the same issue as that question.

Comment: @M.Justin yes, I too also do not exactly remember, but I guess I was finding something which can bind the value for the additional column out of the box. (sounds a bit stupid)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but here - you can possibly extend the entity.

Say your entity class is `Drink`

```
class Drink {

String weight;

String size;

//other getter setter constructor etc
}
```

And then you have a service from which you are able to fetch a value from a column:

```
class FlavorService {

static String getFlavor(){ /*can be static since it's only retrieval/idempotent*/ };

}
```

So now what you can do is create an extended class

```
class FlavoredDrink extends Drink{ 

String flavor;

    public FlavoredDrink (String weight, String size){
        super(weight, size);
        this.flavor = FlavorService.getFlavor();
    }

}
```

Then you just have to use `FlavoredDrink`.

Comment: I want to fetch the value through a query.

Comment: Yes, then just include the query within `FlavorService#getFlavor()`. Or were you asking for the sql query?